# Mantenimiento de índices SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, indices

Con la siguiente consulta obtuve la fragmentación de los indices de las BDs alojadas dentro de una instancia y necesito implementar el mantenimiento de los mismos.

```
SELECT S.name as 'Schema',
T.name as 'Table',
I.name as 'Index',
DDIPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
DDIPS.page_count
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS DDIPS
INNER JOIN sys.tables T ON T.object_id = DDIPS.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas S on T.schema_id = S.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.indexes I on I.object_id = DDIPS.object_id
AND DDIPS.index_id = I.index_id
WHERE DDIPS.database_id = DB_ID()
AND I.name IS NOT NULL
AND DDIPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 0
ORDER BY [Table] ASC
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ejecutar el comando REORGANIZE/REBUILD según sea la necesidad, el resultado muestra Command(s) completed successfully., sin embargo, al consultar nuevamente la fragmentación veo que no se realizo ninguna mejora.

```
 ALTER INDEX IDX_State ON WorkflowInstance REORGANIZE;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisando el espacio que tiene asignado la BD se encuentra así. Me pueden asesorar si es suficiente con asignar mas espacio a la BD o que otros factores se deben tomar en cuenta, por favor?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes mostrar, por favor, tu índice de fragmentación antes y después de la operación `REORGANIZE`? (Query e imagen, de ser posible) O, nos puedes decir cómo sabes que tu índice está fragmentado?

Comment: @Arriel  esa s la consulta que estoy utilizando

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El mantenimiento de índices es un tema que llega a ser complicado porque hay muchos aspectos a tomar en cuenta. Sin embargo, trataré de mantener lo más escencial respecto a tu pregunta.

La información de SQL Server se almacena físicamente en páginas de 8KB que conforman cada archivo de la base de datos. La fragmentación (promedio) es que tan dividida está la información entre las múltiples páginas. Esta se produce al querer insertar información que no cabe en una página y la página se tiene que dividir en 2 páginas. Para corregir este problema, hay 2 opciones `REORGANIZE` (reorganizar) y `REBUILD` (reconstruir).

Usualmente se recomienda reorganizar los índices con una fragmentación mayor a 15 y reconstruir cuando es mayor a 30. Esto es porque la reorganización consume menos recursos, pero la reconstrucción es más efectiva. Es por ello que no ves una gran diferencia al reorganizar una tabla con más del 90% de fragmentación promedio. Lo que tienes que hacer es reconstruir los índices. Ahora, para tablas tan pequeñas como `WorkflowSchedule` que todo indica que podrían caber en una sola hoja, es inútil tratar de bajar la fragmentación porque por diseño va a organizarse en múltiples hojas. Sin embargo, otras como `WorkflowProcess` sí deben de ser monitoreadas para mantener la fragmentación en niveles bajos y evitar problemas de rendimiento. Es posible que también haya que revisar su diseño y la forma de insertar datos para prevenir la fragmentación además de corregirla.

Por último, la comparación entre el espacio reservado y el espacio usado de tu base de datos no tiene una relación directa con la fragmentación. Claro, a mayor fragmentación más diferencia verás, pero eso puede deberse a otros factores. Aún así, la diferencia es relativamente poca y no es algo de que preocuparse. Para un mantenimiento integral y automatizado te recomiendo que revises las opciones de [Ola Hallengren](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html) o de [MinionWare](https://www.minionware.net/products/reindex/).

Por último, te dejo la consulta que uso regularmente para darme información del almacenamiento de la base de datos.

```
WITH ctePages
     AS (SELECT reservedpages = SUM(a.total_pages), 
                usedpages = SUM(a.used_pages), 
                pages = SUM(CASE  
                            -- XML-Index and FT-Index and semantic index internal tables are not considered "data", but is part of "index_size"  
                                WHEN it.internal_type IN(202, 204, 207, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 221, 222, 236)
                                  THEN 0
                                WHEN a.type <> 1 AND p.index_id < 2
                                  THEN a.used_pages
                                WHEN p.index_id < 2
                                  THEN a.data_pages
                            ELSE 0 END)
         FROM   sys.partitions AS p
         JOIN sys.allocation_units AS a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
         LEFT JOIN sys.internal_tables AS it ON p.object_id = it.object_id),
cteDBSize AS (
    SELECT  dbsize  = SUM(CONVERT(BIGINT, CASE WHEN STATUS&64 = 0 THEN size ELSE 0 END)), 
            logsize = SUM(CONVERT(BIGINT, CASE WHEN STATUS&64 <> 0 THEN size ELSE 0 END))
    FROM   dbo.sysfiles
)
SELECT database_size     = CONVERT( decimal(10, 2), dbsize * 8192 / POWER(1024.,3)), 
       unallocated_space = CONVERT( decimal(10, 2), CASE WHEN dbsize >= reservedpages 
                                                        THEN( dbsize - reservedpages ) * 8192 / POWER(1024.,3) 
                                                        ELSE 0 END), 
       reserved          = CONVERT( decimal(10, 2), reservedpages * 8192 / POWER(1024.,3)),
       data              = CONVERT( decimal(10, 2), pages * 8192 / POWER(1024.,3)),
       index_size        = CONVERT( decimal(10, 2), ( usedpages - pages ) * 8192 / POWER(1024.,3)),
       unused            = CONVERT( decimal(10, 2), ( reservedpages - usedpages ) * 8192 / POWER(1024.,3))
FROM   ctePages
CROSS JOIN cteDBSize;
```